# jDateChooser1 needs to be converted to varchar to be stored in database how can I do this?

Tags: java, datetime, netbeans

Currently on my jframe I have jdatechooser and am using this code:

```
java.util.Date utilDate = (java.util.Date) jDateChooser1.getDate();
java.sql.Date sqlDate = new java.sql.Date(utilDate.getTime());
prepStat.setDate(6, sqlDate);
```

but when I click add on the jframe this is the only data that doesn't get entered at all

The variable is called Target_Date and is set to varchar if that helps.

Comment: I recommend that you use the `date` datatype of your RDBMS (if it has got one) and don’t use `varchar` for a date. And I recommend that you don’t use the two `Date` classes. They are poorly designed and long outdated. Use `LocalDate` from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/). And then `prepStat.setObject(6, yourLocalDate);`.

Answer (score 1):

### Recommended solution: use the `date` datatype of your RDBMS

Provided that you database engine offers a `date` datatype (the vast majority do), use it. And use `LocalDate` from java.time, the modern Java date and time API, rather than the two `Date` classes. They are poorly designed and long outdated. You probably can’t change the return type from your date picker, but then convert first thing when you receive it.

```
    Date utilDate = jDateChooser1.getDate();
    LocalDate localDate = utilDate.toInstant()
            .atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault())
            .toLocalDate();
    prepStat.setObject(6, localDate);
```

This requires a JDBC 4.2 compliant driver, you probably have got that.

### Discouraged solution: convert to `String`

If you are not allowed to change the datatype in the database, convert to a `String` in Java:

```
    prepStat.setString(6, localDate.toString());
```

The rest is the same as before.

### What went wrong in your code?

It’s not something I know, but I suspect that you are not allowed to use `PreparedStatement.setDate` with a `varchar` column.

### Link

- [Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use java.time.